# Laravel Serve command does not respect --env parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-5.8, laravel-dusk2

To be able to run Browser tests directly in my IDE (without using the artisan dusk command), I want to run `php artisan serve --env=dusk.local`. While it indeed starts the local PHP server, it uses the wrong database. It uses the database specified in `.env` not the one in `.env.dusk.local`.
I ran `php artisan cache:clear` thousands of times, but it doesn't change anything.
Running things like `php artisan migrate --env=...` works.

Is there a way to achieve my goal without needing to rename my `.env.dusk.local` file to `.env` before each test?

Comment: maybe try
`php artisan serve --env=.env.dusk.local`?

Comment: The docs state that you only need the suffix of .env. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/testing#environment 
Please mind that I wrote, that other commands work as intended.

Comment: This has been fixed in the latest release of Laravel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Laravel 5.8: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27828

<s>There is currently no solution (other than downgrading to Laravel 5.7).</s>

It has been fixed in the latest release 5.8.7.